Is there a Laravel Blade equivalent to React Fragments (<>...</>)?
In React, I can use fragments (<>...</>) to group multiple elements without adding extra nodes to the DOM:
<>
    <div>First element</div>
    <div>Second element</div>
</>

Is there a similar concept in Laravel Blade so I can use it on Livewire components? I want to avoid using an empty div when creating some components since Livewire only supports one HTML element per component.

<>...</>  is necessary for React because all components need to render one root element. As far as I know, Laravel blade does not have this restriction so there is no need  for fragments to exist

@apokryfos You are right! I forgot to say that it's for Livewire
"Livewire only supports one HTML element per component."

I'm not sure how Livewire works and why this limitation exists so you could either dig into the source code (if you enjoy that kind of activity) to figure out if there are ways around the limitation or make a feature request in their GitHub repo. If they need to have a root element for a component to keep track of some sort of internal state then I don't think there's much you can do about this that will not end up adding more elements to the DOM

Yes, Laravel Blade has a feature similar to React's fragments
Option 1:
You can also use the @once directive to prevent unnecessary wrapping and ensure the content is only rendered once. This is useful when dealing with elements like inline scripts or components that should be rendered conditionally.
@once
    <div>First element</div>
    <div>Second element</div>
@endonce

Option 2:
You can directly include Blade partials without adding extra wrapper elements using the @include directive.
Create a Blade partial view:
<!-- resources/views/partials/elements.blade.php -->
<div>First element</div>
<div>Second element</div>

Include it in your main Blade template:
@include('partials.elements')

This will include the content without adding any unnecessary wrapper elements.
